# Combining Spring shell and boot together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-shell

I am new to Spring, so after whole day of faling attempts I need to ask ;)

Is it possible to combine [Spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and [Spring shell](http://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/) together?

My use case is to build a jar which contains webapp (Spring-boot embeds jetty or tomcat by default) and at the same time is able to execute some project commands from shell. Quarts is not an option. It would be great if these commands and webapp share the same application context.

There are two classes in my src/main/java (plus some commands and controllers in other directories)

Application.java

```
package dk.mrok.carmonitor;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Bootstrap webapp
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Cli.java

```
package dk.mrok.carmonitor;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap;

public class Cli {

    /**
     * Main class that delegates to Spring Shell's Bootstrap class in order to simplify debugging inside an IDE
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bootstrap.main(args);
    }

}
```

This is my build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

jar {
    baseName = 'carmonitor-backend'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'}
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = "dk.mrok.carmonitor.Cli"

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.shell:spring-shell:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Unfortunatley the resulting jar is spring-shell project, not webapp.
Executing ./build/script/carmonitor (I expected shell project here) outputs

```
Error: Could not find or load main class dk.mrok.carmonitor.Cli
```

Any suggestions what do I do wrong?

Comment: Just make it a web application, add the `spring-boot-starter-remote-shell` and write your commands. That should work. You shouldn't create 2 separate applications (that is what you are doing right now).

Comment: Using spring-boot-starter-remote-shell helps a lot. thanks

Comment: @mrok how did you solve this ?

Comment: @vishal please take a look at example https://github.com/mrok/spring-web-shell-example

Answer (score 1):

[This project on Github](https://github.com/linux-china/spring-boot-starter-shell) worked for me.
I cloned the repo, built the project and installed locally. Then used it as a dependency.

And alternative way is described [here](https://comsysto.com/blog-post/spring-shell), where they add all Spring-Shell core components as well as the beans for the JLineShellComponent and the CommandLine to the Boot ApplicationContext. However, it resulted in stack overflow when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I use wrong version springshell in my springboot project,the version is too old,then I run application,there still didn't came out a shell:> out let me input;
when i use new version springshell,then run application,after springboot's web init ,"shell:>" entry appear.[image]